# asp disabled or enabled buttons

Tags: asp-classic

I have a button that I want to disable and enable.
I have tried something like this:

`tryprint = "Disabled"`

`<input type="submit" value="Stop" name="action" <%= tryprint %>/>`

and it isn't working. How can I disable and enable button with a parameter tryprint?

Comment: Can't you use JavaScript instead?

Comment: I found an answer:
<% if tryprint then %>
<input type="submit" value="Start" name="action" Disabled="disabled"/>
<% else %>
<input type="submit" value="Start" name="action" />
<% end if %>

Comment: Ok, great. You can post an answer to your own question and accept it if you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to use If..Then statement, you can have it all in one string:

```
tryprint="disabled=""disabled"""
<input type="submit" value="Stop" name="action" <%= tryprint %>/>
```